# Missing prototype methods in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I'm retrieving plain json data via my service and then attaching some behaviour to it via a constructor and prototype methods. 
When this object is returned from the service to the controller,  I can see via developer tools that it has the correct 'class'  name,  however none of the methods are available. 
When testing my classes and protoypes outside of an angularjs app,  they work as expected. 
The below is my service:

```
app.factory('characterService', function($http) {
    var _chars = [];
    return {
        getCharacters: function() {
            return $http.get('app/resources/charsheets.js').then(function(d) {
                _chars = [];
                var data = d.data.characters;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    _chars.push(new Character(data[i]));
                }
                return _chars;
            });
        }
    };
    Character.prototype.getStatBonus = function(statAbbr) {
        var bonus = 0;
        if (statAbbr && statAbbr != '') {
            var baseStats = this["baseStats"];
            for (var i = 0; i < baseStats.length; i++) {
                if (baseStats[i].abv == statAbbr) {
                    //More stuff normally happens, but for the sake of brevity
                    //it has been reduced to a simple assignment
                    bonus = baseStats[i].totalBonus;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return bonus;
    };

});

function Character(raw) {
     //Stuff here
   }
```

My very basic controller:

```
app.controller('characterController',function($scope,characterService)
    {
        $scope.model = {};

        characterService.getCharacters().then(function(data){
            $scope.model.characters = data;
            $scope.model.currentCharacter = data[0];
        });

    });
```

Some sample markup:

```
<div>

    {{model.currentCharacter.getStatBonus('Ag')}}

</div>
```

The error I am getting is that `getStatBonus` is undefined, even though the object is of the Character type (confirmed via developer tools).

Is what I'm attempting to do even possible?
Thanks

Comment: Get to the place where you can post your code and do it.

Comment: @PM77-1 There you go, I hope it helps!

Comment: when you 'return' in your factory function 'Character' is defined because of 'function hoisting', but the code that modifies the Character prototype is not being executed because you 'return' before it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem... I was declaring the constructors and prototype methods in the body of the service.

I declared them outside of it and it works but not sure if that is the angular way of doing things